# Inserting new element in an element in an array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap

Good evening mates!. I was considering about how can i add a new element into an existing element in an array.
This is because i want to deal with colisions in hash maps by adding the new element in the index where a previous element has been stored.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.splice()` method like:

`yourArray.splice(indexOfCurrentElement, 1, newElement)`

This will remove the current element and insert new element in its place

Comment: But i dont want to remove the previous item

Comment: then use ```yourArray.splice(indexOfCurrentElement, 0, newElement)```. The middle argument is the number of items you want to remove starting from the index specified, so if you set it to 0, no item will be removed.

Comment: This is not what i need. I have to add elements in the same index of previous element if the hash is the same.

Comment: @PabloCarreroGarcia please take more time to write out your question in depth. Right now, it's just not clear enough I think.

Comment: Problem fixed. What i wanted to do is to manage collisions in hash tables by adding new elements in the index where a previous value has been stored. I solved with this:  if (hashmap[position]) {
        hashmap[position].push([word])

    }
    else {
        hashmap[position] = [word]
    }